# Telerik Dropdowns lists selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using Radcombo box . I want to pass get the selected value of the drop down list in a page , and pass it to different page  and get the same value selected for the drop dwon in the 2nd page.

But I am unable to capture the value.Only getting the index here.

I tried

```
           ddl2.SelectedIndex
           ddl2.SelectedItem.Text
           ddl2.SelectedValue
```

for sending the value. But it is passing the index of the value only.
Also , in the 2nd page I need to assign this value to drop dwon list .
So,  I used

```
           ddl2.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32((Request.QueryString["No2"]));
           ddl3.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32((Request.QueryString["No3"]));
```

But this are also not able to select the proper value. Any suggestions?

Now I can pass values successfully to the 2nd page using query string ..But while assigning the value from quer string to ddl  list I am getting null value each time..

Here is the piece of code that I tried.I tried both of the below lines.but with each case value is coming to the RHS..but on the LHS its coming as Null.

```
          ddl2.SelectedItem.Value Request.QueryString["No2"].ToString();
          ddl2.FindItemByValue(Request.QueryString["No2"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Comment: Can you show the markup for `ddl2`?

Comment: @jadarnel27: here it is :                               <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbSearchOaO" runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="true"
                AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                Width="200px"
                DataSourceID="odsOwnedAndOperated"
                DataTextField="Owned_And_Operated_Nm"
                DataValueField="Owned_And_Operated_Id"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="PopulateApplicationTypeDropDown"
                >
            </telerik:RadComboBox>

Comment: First focus on getting the value from the RadComboBox into the query string - this should be pretty straight forward as per my answer. If you still have trouble try getting it to work on a fresh page with nothing else on it - if you succeed you'll know something else on your page is interfering

Comment: It looks like you're new here =)  Please [edit] your post to add that relevant code (rather than typing it into a comment).

Comment: ddl2.SelectedItem.Value Request.QueryString["No2"].ToString(); - this isn't going to work, it's as if you're trying to change the value of the selected item instead of changing which item is selected. ddl2.FindItemByValue(Request.QueryString["No2"].ToString()).Selected = true; - this should work, I can't see anything wrong with it. Have you tried setting a break-point and stepping through your code? 
Aslo the code I gave in my answer should work too: RadComboBox2.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["value"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a way to do this:

Page1.aspx:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="A" Text="A" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="B" Text="B" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnNextPage" runat="server" Text="Next Page" OnClick="btnNextPage_Click" />
```

Page1.aspx.cs:

```
protected void btnNextPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx?value=" + RadComboBox1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Page2.aspx:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox2" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="A" Text="A" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="B" Text="B" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Page2.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        RadComboBox2.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["value"];
    }
}
```

Other ways to achieve this include using a [multiview control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx) instead of separate pages, or [using the postbackurl property to postback to a different page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (instead of using the query string)